# Google Maps Tiles Skewed with Flexbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, flexbox

I'm trying to create a layout with a scrolling left column (with images as links) and a fixed full screen right column displaying Google maps. I can't figure out why the map is displaying as skewed. 
[Here's a screnshot of my problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDHKJ.png)

```js
$(window)
  .resize(function() {
    var h = $(window).height(),
      offsetTop = 40; // Calculate the top offset

    $("#map-canvas").css("height", h - offsetTop);
  })
  .resize();
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0px;
  display: flex;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

.column {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-left: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#left {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: 40%;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#right {
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: 60%;
  flex: 1;
}

.top-left {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
}

.top-right {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
}

.bottom {
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

ul {
  display: inline-flex;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

img {
  min-width: 450px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#map_canvas {
  flex: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="left" class="column">
    <div class="bottom">
      <li><img class="img-responsive" src="http://s3.india.com/travel/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Mumbai-Gateway-625x470.jpg" data-src="http://s3.india.com/travel/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Mumbai-Gateway-625x470.jpg" style="opacity: 0.5;"></li>
      <li><img class="img-responsive" src="http://s3.india.com/travel/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Mumbai-Gateway-625x470.jpg" data-src="http://s3.india.com/travel/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Mumbai-Gateway-625x470.jpg" style="opacity: 0.5;"></li>
      <li><img class="img-responsive" src="http://s3.india.com/travel/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Mumbai-Gateway-625x470.jpg" data-src="http://s3.india.com/travel/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Mumbai-Gateway-625x470.jpg" style="opacity: 0.5;"></li>
      <li><img class="img-responsive" src="http://s3.india.com/travel/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Mumbai-Gateway-625x470.jpg" data-src="http://s3.india.com/travel/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Mumbai-Gateway-625x470.jpg" style="opacity: 0.5;"></li>
      <li><img class="img-responsive" src="http://s3.india.com/travel/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Mumbai-Gateway-625x470.jpg" data-src="http://s3.india.com/travel/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Mumbai-Gateway-625x470.jpg" style="opacity: 0.5;"></li>
      <li><img class="img-responsive" src="http://s3.india.com/travel/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Mumbai-Gateway-625x470.jpg" data-src="http://s3.india.com/travel/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Mumbai-Gateway-625x470.jpg" style="opacity: 0.5;"></li>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="right" class="column">
    <div class="bottom">
      <div id="map-canvas">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    function initMap() {
      // Styles a map in night mode.
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), {
        center: {
          lat: 40.674,
          lng: -73.945
        },
        zoom: 12
      });
    }
  </script>

  <!-- script references -->

  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAK1QRzq4tKEN63PxIA6jKfyypkoRn326M&callback=initMap" async defer></script>

</body>
```

[Here's my codepen link](https://codepen.io/ethereality/pen/vWoRgX), if that's helpful.

I'd like it to look something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/290/), but I couldn't figure out what exactly I am doing wrong.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance for helping out a beginner!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Maps uses HTML `<img />` tag to render the map.

In your code you have:

```
img {
  min-width: 450px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

You are **overwriting** the styles of Google Maps **`<img />`** tags when you run the code.

The proper way is limiting to the zone where the image is going to render, by using:

```
.container-content img {
  margin: 0px;
  min-width: 450px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

By the way, you're missing the `<ul>` tags in the HTML.

See this demo is according to your [link](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/290/).

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.flexbox-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100vh;
}

.flexbox-container #left_container {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 0;
}

.container-content {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100vh;
}

.flexbox-container #map_container {
  margin: 0;
}

#map_canvas {
  flex: 2;
}

.container-content img {
  margin: 0;
  min-width: 450px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flexbox-container">
  <div id="left_container">
    <div class="container-content">
      <ul>
        <li><img class="img-responsive" src="http://s3.india.com/travel/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Mumbai-Gateway-625x470.jpg" data-src="http://s3.india.com/travel/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Mumbai-Gateway-625x470.jpg" style="opacity: 0.5;"></li>
        <li><img class="img-responsive" src="http://s3.india.com/travel/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Mumbai-Gateway-625x470.jpg" data-src="http://s3.india.com/travel/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Mumbai-Gateway-625x470.jpg" style="opacity: 0.5;"></li>
        <li><img class="img-responsive" src="http://s3.india.com/travel/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Mumbai-Gateway-625x470.jpg" data-src="http://s3.india.com/travel/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Mumbai-Gateway-625x470.jpg" style="opacity: 0.5;"></li>
        <li><img class="img-responsive" src="http://s3.india.com/travel/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Mumbai-Gateway-625x470.jpg" data-src="http://s3.india.com/travel/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Mumbai-Gateway-625x470.jpg" style="opacity: 0.5;"></li>
        <li><img class="img-responsive" src="http://s3.india.com/travel/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Mumbai-Gateway-625x470.jpg" data-src="http://s3.india.com/travel/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Mumbai-Gateway-625x470.jpg" style="opacity: 0.5;"></li>
        <li><img class="img-responsive" src="http://s3.india.com/travel/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Mumbai-Gateway-625x470.jpg" data-src="http://s3.india.com/travel/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Mumbai-Gateway-625x470.jpg" style="opacity: 0.5;"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</div>

<script>
  function initMap() {
    // Styles a map in night mode.
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: {
        lat: 40.674,
        lng: -73.945
      },
      zoom: 12
    });
  }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAK1QRzq4tKEN63PxIA6jKfyypkoRn326M&callback=initMap" async></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!